# Align items centrally in a div

Tags: reactjs

**Goal:** Align items centrally in div

See picture here (notice every watch is shifted to the left):

[image]

I'm trying to render each item in `productcard` centrally.

Currenty, each `productCard__container` renders to left.

Here is my `ProductCard.js` code:

```js
return (
    <div className="productcard">
      <button onClick={(e) => history.push(`/product/${id}`)}>
        <div className="productCard__container">
          <img src={image} />
          <h1>{brand}</h1>
          <h2>{name}</h2>
          <p>${price}</p>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
```

...and the CSS code:

```
.productcard {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: black;
}

.productCard__container {
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css flex box

```css
.productcard {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```